# What does it mean when you do or say something ''forward''?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

I don't really know what it means but does it have something to do with being rude or something like that?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? Admittedly the word has several different meanings. The Macmillan online dictionary defines _forward_ in this sense as **very confident and direct about saying what you think, in a way that is not socially suitable**.

Comment: @KateBunting  please explain more about that definition you have just stated because I don't really it understand very well

Comment: Suppose you are a visitor in the home of someone you don't know very well, especially if they are older than you are, and you start behaving as you would in the home of an intimate friend. Or suppose you meet an important person at a formal ceremony and make a cheeky remark to  them, perhaps saying that you find the ceremony boring. That behaviour could be described as _forward_.

Comment: @KateBunting is it a bad thing to do or say something forward?

Comment: @puppetsock. For me, the polite and restrained word “forward” denotes behavior that *begins* to overstep the bounds of good manners. In its narrow sense, it means “*putting yourself forward*” - going a bit too far in an approach than others might think appropriate. A possible synonym is “pushy”. Your example describes extreme rudeness that doesn’t fit. It’s not even clear that you have described an interpersonal approach rather than random abuse. (It is like saying “annoying” is the usual adjective for a cancer diagnosis.  Deliberate understatement won’t help むさつ. )

Comment: "forward" has many meanings. Please edit your question to give examples of sentences where you an unsure of the meaning.

Comment: Whether or not it's 'a bad thing' is a matter of opinion, but to call someone's behaviour forward implies a criticism (that it's not appropriate to the situation).